# Entity Framework Extensibility with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

If you want to extend Entity Framework, Microsoft offers a project template for getting started in Visual Studio 2010:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtStartKit

However, this template is for Visual Studio 2010 and there is no newer version. If you change the `extension.vsixmanifest` file, you can install it into VS2012 and it's possible to build the project. But after installing the generated VSIX file, nothing happens in the Entity Designer. The extension is listed as 'installed', but the additional properties do not appear in the designer.

**Has anyone managed to build a Visual Studio 2012 extension that adds custom properties to the Properties Dialog of Entity Framework 5 Model First?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to go to the [discussion page](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtStartKit/Thread/List.aspx) and take a look at the first thread. The author claims he has a version that supposedly on VS 2012. The link he provides seems to have a type but here is the link to the post on [his blog](http://www.jsrsoft.co.uk/blog/post/Entity-Framework-Starter-Kit-alternative)

Comment: Unfortunately, all download links provided by that author lead to `404 - File or directory not found.` errors.

Comment: Maybe you could make him aware of the problem by commenting on the post?

Comment: Yeap I contacted him through the site, got the following link: https://github.com/jradxl/Custom-Text-Templating-Host